# Downgrade then upgrade iCloud storage

Tags: iphone, icloud

I used to have 2TB of iCloud storage then for several months of not paying, I was downgraded to 5GB free storage.  What happens to the data I previously had?  Will it get deleted?

Comment: What is the answer then, @grgarside

Comment: Have you taken a look at the linked duplicate? Feel free to [edit] if the linked duplicate doesn’t answer the question

Comment: @grgarside okay, but can you please just answer this - my 2TB worth of data won't be deleted despite canceling subscription, correct? Yes/No  Thank you!

Comment: @Borgata_Princess Ofcourse the data will be deleted. It seems you have 30 days to retrieve them.